# mbed uvisor dynamically load binary

Tags: c++, arm, mbed

I have a NXP FRDM-K64F board where I have uvisor running diferent modules in boxes. Is there a way to load the code of one box from an external file? Can uvisor handle boxes dynamically? I would want to create an aplication that can get a binary and set it on a box. Is that supported?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but uVisor boxes are determined at compile/link time and cannot be altered during runtime. Which is good, because otherwise you could break the integrity of the boxes when someone takes over your device (due to a buffer overflow or something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uVisor at the moment does **not** support modular applications, where each box has its own firmware that can be loaded independently from others.

As [Jan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250411/mbed-uvisor-dynamically-load-binary#comment71676413_42250411), boxes are determined at compile and link time and end up in a unique, monolithic firmware. Boxes' capabilities are expressed via static ACLs, which are enumerated at runtime and checked for consistency and compatibility (e.g. two boxes cannot claim exclusive ownership of the same peripheral).

A future implementation might allow a more modular setup, as there would be ways to check the integrity of a newly provided box firmware and to reconcile the new ACLs with the existing ones. We don't have plans for it yet, but the current implementation does not exclude that capability.